# Divide a line into two segments based on Phi, Golden Ratio

Tags: javascript

I have a line length I'm dividing into two segments. Rather than spit in half or use some other arbitrary value, I wish to use Phi, or the Golden Ratio, to determine the length of each segment.

For example, given a height value of 100, I need the return of 61.8 and 38.2.

---

In this case I'm programming a dynamically generated SVG shape using JavaScript. A form is used to provide the inputs, for example height of the shape. There are corners at the bottom that use [Bezier](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-svg-quadratic-curves/) curves. I wish to start the bezier curve at a point along the side determined by the Golden Ratio, or "phi" which is approximately 1.618.

```
<svg width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 0 0">
    <path d="" />
</svg>

<script>

let height = 100
let vertical = 38.2
let corner = 61.8

// d = "m 300 300 v 38.2 c 0 100 38.2 100 100 100"
document.querySelector('path').setAttribute("d",
    "m 300 300 v " + vertical + " c 0 " + corner + " " + vertical + " " + corner + " " + corner + " " + corner
)

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two [Golden Ratio](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/golden-ratio.html) (or "phi", which is a ratio of approximately 1.618) formulas—of a line made up of line segments a and b, consecutively—are:

```
//      a       b
// X---------X-----X

a/b = 1.618...
// and
(a + b) / a = 1.618...
```

Having neither a nor b, but having the total line length, the second ratio is used to determine first a, then b:

```
// 1) Starting with formula: 
(a + b) / a = 1.618...

// 2)  Rename (a + b) to represent the known value:
(total_line_length) / a = 1.618...

// 3) Isolate variable a:
total_line_length / a * a = a * 1.618... // multiply each side by a
total_line_length = a * 1.618...
total_line_length / 1.618... = a * 1.618... / 1.618... // divide each side by 1.618...

a = total_line_length / 1.618...

// 4) Get b:
b = total_line_length - a
```

Using the last two equations write a Javascript function that accepts the total line length:

```
function getPhiSegs (total_line_length) {
    let major = total_line_length / 1.61803398874989484820
    let minor = total_line_length - major
    return {"phi_major": rndH(major), "phi_minor": rndH(minor)}
}

function rndH(val) { // round value to nearest hundreth
    return Math.round(val * 100) / 100
}
```

Returns:

```
> getPhiSegs(100)
> { phi_major: 61.8, phi_minor: 38.2 }
```

Using `getPhiSegs` function to define an SVG path:

```
let height = document.forms[0].elements['height'].value
let height_phi_segments = getPhiSegs(height)
let vertical = height_phi_segments.phi_minor
let corner = height_phi_segments.phi_major

document.querySelector('path').setAttribute("d",
    "m 300 300 v " + vertical + " c 0 " + corner + " " + vertical + " " + corner + " " + corner + " " + corner
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve the equation that defines phi, first of all.  From wikipedia:

[image]

```js
const phi = (1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;

console.log(phi);

const getSegments=(h)=>{return {'a': h/phi, 'b': h-h/phi};}

console.log(getSegments(100));
```

So in context of your existing code:

```js
const phi = (1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;
const getSegments=(h)=>{return {'a': h/phi, 'b': h-h/phi};}
let height = 100;
let segments = getSegments(height);

let pathDef = 
  `m 300 300 v ${segments.b} 
   c 0 ${segments.a} ${segments.b} 
   ${segments.a} ${segments.a} ${segments.a}`;

console.log(pathDef);

document.querySelector('path').setAttribute("d", pathDef);
```

```html
<svg width="12cm" height="4cm" 
  viewBox="0 0 300 600"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="1.1"
>
  <path d="" 
    fill="none" stroke="blue" 
    stroke-width="20"
  />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please explain the benefit of solving phi over hard coding the solution? In other words, why use `(1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2` instead of `1.618033988749895` ?

Comment: `phi = (1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2` is nearly as simple to write as `phi = 1.618033988749895 ` and while the accuracy (I assume) is either the same or so close to the same that you will never notice, I think the equation is more semantically significant.  The solution is well known, so it doesn't really take any effort to find, as a matter of fact, no more effort than it would take to find the value to 15 digits.